# How to increase/decrease a number by a step fixing any potenital mismatch might occur?

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to write logic for increase/decrease number by a giving step
for example when the step is set to `0.3` and the giving number value is 0; then the increment will be `[0.3, 0.6, 0.9, ...etc]`.
and when the giving number value is `1.4`and the step is `0.3` then increment should be by `0.1`to fall on the `1.5` which is the fifth increment.

Here is my attempt:

```js
 export class Spinner { 
        increase(currentValue, step) {
           const step = step || 1;
           const decimalSize = getDecimalSize(step);
           const current = normalize(currentValue, decimalSize);
           const ratio = Math.ceil(normalize(current / step, decimalSize));
           let increment = normalize(ratio * step, decimalSize);
         
        if (
            normalize(current % step, decimalSize) === 0 ||
            current === increment ||
            normalize(current % step, decimalSize) === 1
        ) {
            increment = normalize(current + step, decimalSize);
        }
    }
}

export function getDecimalSize(value: number) {
    if (Math.floor(value) === value) return 0;
    return value.toString().split(".")[1]?.length || 0;
}

export function normalize(value: number, decimalSize: number): number {
    decimalSize = decimalSize || 1;
   const n = Math.pow(10, decimalSize + 1);
   return Math.round(value * n) / n;
}
```

This works fine for positive numbers, but it does not work well with negative numbers

for example if the current value is -2 and step is 0.3 I get -1.8 instead of -1.7

Comment: I think you can fix that using `Math.abs(current % step)`.

Comment: I don't full understand what you're doing but it is probably more complicated then it has to be, I think you can do all that using something like `const currentStep = step - Math.abs(value % step)`